# How is my Android phone automatically recognized by adb on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I am moving from Windows over to Ubuntu 14.04 for my Android application development. By biggest worry was to figure out how to make Android devices work with adb on Ubuntu. Various articles on the Internet talk about creating /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file and adding specific information for each Android device.

However, I didn't do any of that. I just plugged in my Android phone to the USB port and typed "adb devices." There was a question on my phone about trusting the attached computer. After I said yes, adb listed that device as usable.

I tried plugging in another phone. Once again, adb just recognized the device.

I don't see any rules for USB under /etc/udev/rules.d directory and I certainly didn't create one. I am just curious on how adb automatically recognized my devices.

Comment: sounds more like a topic for superuser...

Comment: Maybe, the android sdk installs the adb drivers and moreover, linux systems have great driver support, so it wont be much of a hassle, as even i moved recently from windows to Ubuntu 14.04